mod_wsgi can't find MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR, even though I set it
First, I'm new to python. I have two files I want to see working in a browser, and one file is python.
I have XAMPP installed on my windows 10 laptop. The path to XAMPP is C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\server
I have tried installing mod_wsgi multiple times, changing the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR each time to something new. I've tried (as administrator):

set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\server\apache"
set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\server"
set "MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\server\apache\bin"

Each time, when I do pip install mod_wsgi, the console tells me it can't find apache and to set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment variable.
Any suggestions?
